# What does it mean for a function to "preserve the limits of sequences"?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, translation-request

I've translated the English Wikipedia page "Limit of a sequence". What does the following statement mean?

> In fact, any real-valued function f is continuous if and only if it preserves the limits of sequences (though this is not necessarily true when using more general notions of continuity).

I cannot understand the following part: "... it preserves the limits of sequences ...".
Can you write same sentence in a long and clear way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: to which language?

Comment: it preserves the same value of the imagen of any point (the limit of the images for any convergent sequence who goes to the first point, goes to the image of the convergent point of the sequence)

Comment: to Turkish. Current translation is really nonsense.

Comment: remember that for mathematicians, the intuitive notions are important for explain things (at least in spanish, there are words like "the function behaves well with operations" to denote that the function do f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) and f(xy)=f(x)f(y)   )

Comment: We you the word "behave" directly as well. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sorry for bad english. I never had a course of english, learn reading dictionary

Comment: No, they were helpful. You did well! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what they mean.
$f$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ **if and only if**
for any sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots,$,
if $x_n$ converges to $a$, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(a)$.

When you say $x$ **preserves** $y$, that means, "$x$ does not change $y$", or "$x$ keeps $y$ the same". In mathematics if you say that a function $f$ preserves some property $P$, that usually means that if you apply $f$, property $P$ is still true. So if a function $f$ **preserves the limits of sequences**, that means that every sequence limit ($x_n \to a$) is still true when you apply $f$: $f(x_n) \to f(a)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'm familiar with its math. I need to understand the words because I'm translating.

Comment: @frukoprof I have tried to explain in English what "preserves" means. Does that help? Tell me if you do not understand any of the words.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thank you so much :))

Answer (score 2):

I think they simply mean that $f$ is continuous (at $x_0$) iff

$$ \lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} x) = f(x_0). $$

Using sequences then for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $x_n\to x_0$ as $n\to\infty$, we have that

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n) = f(x_0). $$

By the word 'preserves', you may try to replace it with 'conserves', 'keeps', 'retains', or 'upholds'.

Comment: Thank you but I know the mathematical explanation. But I need some verbal answers.

Comment: Well, it means what the mathematics say, but I'll try and edit my answer show what it means intuitively.

Comment: It would be nice if you try to explain why he said "preserve".

Answer (score 0):

In plain English:

A real-valued function $f$ is continuous if, for any sequence that converges, the image by $f$ of the sequence converges, and the limit of the image is the image of the limit.

Comment: Oh thank you for verbal answer! Because I'm translating I need to know what he did mean with that word. Can you tell me why did he say "preserve"?

Comment: Well, he meant what I wrote, more or less $f$ is compatible with limits of sequences, or like when we say linear maps preserve addition of vectors or scalar multiplication.